# custom attributes in magento virtual products

Tags: php, magento

I've gotten alot of answers from here over the years, and never had to create an account to ask...but now im a little stuck, and need help.

Its probably something simple and stupid...but...

I'm making a category of "Service Agents" set up as virtual products, which I have disabled as many system Attributes as possible, and added new attributes specific for this category.

While I was testing, it worked fine, displayed the attributes if they weren't empty....so I went ahead and inserted all Service Agents, around 200 of them.
...now when I added links to each category, the service agents (virtual products) show ok, but ALL attributes are empty...

What am I missing?

I am using a Custom Layout for the categories:

```
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>/catalog/product/list/service-agents.phtml</template></action>
```

In the PHTML file im displaying the products if not empty, like:

```
$store = $_product->getAttributeText('agent_store');

<?php if(!empty($store)):?>
    <li>
        <strong><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('agent_store')->getStoreLabel(); ?>&nbsp;</strong>
        <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('agent_store') ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now this worked fine while I was testing...The website is Live, I tested this same layout override under a different category when it worked. I've checked all settings over and over, and they're all good.
Products are active, categories are active, attributes are filled and set to "Show on Listing, and Show on front end".

Thanks in advance for any help.
I am NOT a magento expert, and not a scripting expert either...so please answer me like I am a newbie!! hahaha!

=========== UPDATE ============
While playing around with it, and desperate for ideas...I found that it works if the Attribute is a DropDown options list...but NOT if it's a TextField.
maybe this means something to magento gurus out there?

Comment: Have you tried to flush all cache? Normally the view is cached.

Comment: Yeah, I flushed cache, reindexed everything, multiple times. still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with a text field attribute, you should just use the standard `Varien_Object` getter. So in your example it should be this: `$_product->getAgentStore()`.